# git log says I have a fork but i dont

Tags: git, github

For some reason my git log shows that I have a `fork/main` branch, like so:

```
~ git log
commit abc123abc123 (HEAD -> main, origin/main, origin/HEAD)
Author: Me
...

commit xyz789xyz789 (fork/main)
Author: Me
...
```

But locally, I only have 1 branch (main), and on my private github repo, `Forks` shows `0`. What is this thing and how do i get rid of it / understand it?

Probably related but when i do `gh pr create`, it offers me my repo as an option twice. This doesnt happen with my other private repos:

```
? Where should we push the 'testing' branch?  [Use arrows to move, type to filter]
> me/my-private-repo
  me/my-private-repo
  Skip pushing the branch
  Cancel
```

UPDATE:

```
~ git remote -vv
fork    https://github.com/me/my-repo.git (fetch)
fork    https://github.com/me/my-repo.git (push)
origin  https://github.com/me/my-repos-old-name.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/me/my-repos-old-name.git (push)

~ git branch -r
  fork/fix-types  <--- This PR was recently landed and the branch deleted, but never on any kind of fork (at least not that i know of)
  fork/main
  origin/HEAD -> origin/main
  origin/main
```

Comment: What does `git remote -vv` and `git branch -r` show? Please [edit] your question to include this information

Comment: @knittl, updated. for context, i had renamed my repo in github

Comment: So you have two remotes: `origin` and `fork`. Remote branches are always shown as `remotename/branchname`. Now, what was the question again? :)

Comment: im not sure how i got the fork or how to remove it. According to Github's web page there are no forks of my repo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The output of `git remote -vv` and the fact that you say you renamed your repo on GitHub is saying that `fork` is simply your local name for the remote with the new URL, and `origin` is your local name for the remote with the old URL.

From your commit log, it looks like you're still pushing using the old name, but that doesn't matter, because GitHub keeps the old name around as an alias whenever you rename a repo. That's to keep old sandboxes working.

There isn't actually a problem in all this, you could ignore it and keep going with pushing to `origin` using the old URL. But if you want to clean it up so it's less confusing, you can 1) remove the unnecessary `fork` remote, and 2) change the URL for `origin`.

1. Run

   ```
   git remote remove fork
   ```

   to remove the `fork` remote from your sandbox.

   I think it's worth doing this, because the presence of this supposed (misnamed) fork in the logs will indeed continue to be confusing.
2. Run

   ```
   git remote set-url origin https://github.com/me/my-repo.git
   ```

   to make `origin` point to the new URL instead of the old one.

   This is just for tidiness, but it will make no effective difference, since GitHub will keep the old name around forever (well, as long as you don't re-create a new repo with the old name later) as a redirect to the new name. But it will make things clearer in the future, and I guess it avoids using the redirect so it might be (a tiny bit) more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You have 1 repository with 2 remotes `origin` and `fork`.
This is different from having an separate repo made from the original 'upstream' repo - commonly know as forking.

Here are two options to get yourself to a single remote called `origin`:

1. Manage the remotes. What @joanis said (remove->set-url) or:

   1. `git remote remove origin`
   2. `git remote rename fork origin`
2. Clone the repo to a new folder (nuclear, but easy option)